# Implement Gravitec in Next.js Web Application

Tags: push-notification, next.js13

The steps in the Gravitec docs are quite simple.

1. Put the cdn link in the main HTML template of my website, I have pout it inside _document.js in  tag
2. Download/extract .ZIP file (contains manifest.json and push-worker.js). Copy them into the root folder of your website. Extract SDK files (manifest.json and push-worker.js) from the archive, add them to the root folder of my website. I have put these files in public directory.

My implementation goes as follows:

_document.js

```
<Head>
       <script
          src="https://cdn.gravitec.net/storage/<unique ID>/client.js"
          async
        ></script> 
</Head>
```

push-worker.js

```
self[`appKey`] = `<>unique ID`;
self[`hostUrl`] = `https://cdn.gravitec.net/sw`;

self.importScripts(`${self[`hostUrl`]}/worker.js`);
```

manifest.json

```
{
  "name": "Gravitec SDK",
  "gcm_sender_id": "<unique ID>",
  "gcm_user_visible_only": true
}
```

The problem is it worked fine last friday but today once user clicks "Allow" on push notification I get error saying "worker.js:1 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'then') at worker.js:1:32535" and no new subcribed users are being added in gravitec.

Please help me to implement gravitic with next.js in a proper way.